# iOS: simplest, quickest way to request a tiny amount of data from a server?

Tags: ios, web-services, networking

I'm looking for an extremely lightweight way to request a single piece of data from a web server on an iOS device.  Put together a request to a web page e.g. http://www.myserver.com/getlevel?uid=johnsmith; asynchronously send the request, then retrieve the contents of the response (which will be a text file containing just a single integer) and do something with the result as soon as it arrives.

The goals are to minimize bandwidth, maximize speed, and keep the code as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over the server in order to change what is sends back?

Comment: yes, it's my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the most trivial example of iOS code, it would be

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/getlevel?uid=johnsmith"]
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
    [self doSomethingWithString:string];
});
```

Note, if that `doSomethingWithString` is going to update the user interface, you'd do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/getlevel?uid=johnsmith"]
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomethingWithString:string];
    });
});
```

If you can make your server generate JSON data, that might be a better approach, though (that way the server can formulate a proper response, can report errors, your client can detect 404 errors and the like, etc.):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/getlevel?uid=johnsmith"]
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&error];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:kNilOptions
                                                                 error:&error];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomethingWithJsonObject:dictionary];
    });
});
```

Comment: @DanM By the way, you should note that if you are going to be initiating multiple requests (e.g. for different `uid`), you will want to constrain how many simultaneous concurrent operations you dispatch to the background. For that, I might suggest `NSOperationQueue`, but (a) you didn't imply that you were going to be doing multiple requests; and (b) you wanted the simplest possible answer. The `NSOperationQueue` answer is brain-dead simple, too, but I didn't want my answer to be too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon whether your application will expand to include additional webservice calls, you might want to consider AFNetworking - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.  Yes, you do have to install the AFNetworking library in your project, but it is easy to do and then you can enjoy something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

(Code taken from AFNetworking github documentation page).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - if I end up requiring more than the one server call I'll definitely give it a look!